# Axios interceptors runs more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this interceptors that logs the user out if unauthorized. I do, however, get more than a 401 response, and the interceptors does therefore run for as many times as the responses I get (4). Is there a way to make it run only for the first one?

This is my code:

```
api.interceptors.response.use(
(response) => response,
(err) => {
  if (err.response.status === 401 && isLoggedIn) {
    api
      .delete("auth/sign_out")
      .then((resp) => {
        clearLocalStorage();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        clearLocalStorage();
      });
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
  return err;
}
```

);

Comment: Well... a global variable to make your interceptor no-op until it needs to act again?

Comment: the code does basically nothing unless `err.response.status === 401 && isLoggedIn` - is that condition true the 4 times, or is it just the once? it's unclear in your question (you could `isLoggedIn = false` in the `if` code, therefore guaranteeing it won't run again until it becomes true again)

Comment: @Bravo It's true for 4 times, since after it runs the first time, it still considers isLoggedIn true for another 3 re-renders before becoming false

Comment: "3 re-renders"? is `isLoggedIn` a React state atom? Please show how and where you set up this interceptor.

Comment: @AKX isLoggedIn is a global variable, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Well, I guess you should do `isLoggedIn = false` in the inner `.then()`? :D Or a lock/semaphore that only allows a single call of the logout/clear flow.

Comment: @AKX I am using React Context. I tried to set the variable false in the inner then. Still nothing.

Comment: why not set `isLoggedIn = false` **before** `api.delete ....` etc

Comment: @Bravo not gonna say I am sure because I spent a bit on it, but I think I tried that and wouldn't work anyway. The solution AKX wrote below works tho. Thank you

Comment: ahh, my reactjs is rusty :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want something like this to "lock out" the possible re-entrant calls:

```
let isLoggingOut = false; // global

// ...

api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (err) => {
    if (err.response.status === 401 && isLoggedIn) {
      if(!isLoggingOut) {
        isLoggingOut = true;  // disallow re-entrant calls
        try {
          await api.delete('auth/sign_out');
        } catch (deletionError) {
          // throw errors away
        } finally {
          clearLocalStorage();
          isLoggingOut = false;
          isLoggedIn = false; // if the variable is assignable
        }
      }
    }
    return err;
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I tried to set IsLoggedIn false in the then block and it wouldn't work, but this does.